# move the mouse in the model, executing raycaster in mousemove causes high CPU usage

Tags: three.js, raycasting, mousemove

move the mouse in the model, executing raycaster in mousemove causes high CPU usage, when I move the mouse,CPU usage soars to 90%
here is my code:

```
this.container.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
                console.log('intersect：', this.intersect(e, this.camera), this.objects)
                this.lastMove = Date.now()
            })
intersect(event, camera) {
            let raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
            let vector = new THREE.Vector2();
            vector.x = event.clientX / window.innerWidth * 2 - 1;
            vector.y = -event.clientY / window.innerHeight * 2 + 1;
            raycaster.setFromCamera(vector, camera);
            let intersectObj = raycaster.intersectObjects(this.objects, false);
            return intersectObj;
        }
```

Comment: Raycaster checks intersection against all triangles of all objects it crosses.

Comment: How to optimize it?now cpu usage very high?my model has 110,000 vertices

Comment: As an option: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-mesh-bvh-a-plugin-for-fast-geometry-raycasting-and-spatial-queries/26394

Comment: like this:http://vrshowtest.hansa.hansacloud.cn/shisiyun/#/, It seems to only use raycaster, Is it possible to just use raycaster?

Comment: I don't know what this web site uses, but here is that theee-mesh-bvh plug-in, that works very fast. I used it here to fill a mesh with points: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/sand-nefertiti-three-mesh-bvh/29098

Comment: I don't know what it uses yet, i have seen its compiled code, nothing special, i dont know if it has be treat specially? i‘ll try your method now. 3q!